# How to styled image in next.js

Tags: next.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Image from 'next/image'

function Selection() {
    const NavSelection = styled.nav`
        background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    `
    const UlFlex = styled.ul`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        li{
            list-style: none;
        }
    `
    return (
        <div>
        <NavSelection>
        <Image
            src="/logo-crazy-monkey-hd-png-download-800x11312396344-pngfind-crazy-hd-png-840_886.png"
            width={100}
            height={100}
        />
        </NavSelection>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Selection
```

Questions:

- How can I style the image to apply `postion:abloute` to the image component?
- What to apply more stylish in image component (this image is logo, not a photo)?
- So how can I use `styleCompnent` or `className` to position the logo? I tried both, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style={{ STYLE HERE }` in your component to custom it

```
<Image
            src="/logo-crazy-monkey-hd-png-download-800x11312396344-pngfind-crazy-hd-png-840_886.png"
            width={100}
            height={100}
style={{ position: "absolute"}}
        />
```